# undefined error when fetching weather forecast api javascript

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api, openweathermap

I am trying to fetch the weather forecast api json like I did with the current weather api, but it does not seem to work any way I try.

```
    let inOneDay = {
fetchWeather: function(){
    fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Dortmund&units=metric&cnt=1&appid=758fce6dd3722cf25cd213a13bbc5484"
    ).then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

};

I have no idea where I went wrong. I used the same logic to make the code below work:

```
let weather = {
    fetchWeather: function(){
        fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Dortmund&units=metric&appid=758fce6dd3722cf25cd213a13bbc5484"
        ).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => this.displayWeather(data));
    },
    displayWeather: function(data){
        const{icon,description} = data.weather[0];
        const{temp} = data.main;
        document.querySelector(".icon").src = "https://www.openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + ".png";
        document.querySelector(".celsius").innerText = Math.round(temp) + "°C";
        document.querySelector(".desc").innerText = description;
    }

}
```

Grateful for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examining the json reply from that API, it looks like the OP code expects different fields than the service provides.

```js
const result = 
{"cod":"200","message":0,"cnt":1,"list":[{"dt":1631577600,"main":{"temp":13.31,"feels_like":13.05,"temp_min":13.31,"temp_max":15.87,"pressure":1018,"sea_level":1018,"grnd_level":1007,"humidity":90,"temp_kf":-2.56},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":95},"wind":{"speed":1.42,"deg":94,"gust":2.29},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-09-14 00:00:00"}],"city":{"id":2935517,"name":"Dortmund","coord":{"lat":51.5167,"lon":7.45},"country":"DE","population":588462,"timezone":7200,"sunrise":1631595820,"sunset":1631641686}};

const result0 = result.list[0];        // notice .list[0]
const weather0 = result0.weather[0];   // notice weather[0]
const main = result0.main;             // notice main is a sibling prop to weather
const temp = main.temp

console.log(`weather is ${JSON.stringify(weather0)}`);
console.log(`main is ${JSON.stringify(main)}`);
console.log(`temp is ${temp}`);
```

Be sure to check for errors before dereferencing the result. It also looks like the api provides a `cnt` prop which might indicate the number of elements in the list.